# Office Add-in Ribbon Button Sizes and Properties Documentation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, office-addins

I'm creating a custom ribbon for an outlook addin, but the button sizes, large, medium, and small are not defined anywhere.  What are the size I should use for large/medium/small images in Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton.Button ?

Will it autoresize or is there a certain size I need to use?

EDIT:  Seems in properties for the button you can change ControlSize to large.  But my second edit is the question I now need answered.

EDIT2:  Is there documentation for the properities for ribbons in Visual Studio 2013?  As in what all the different properties do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 16x16 - small
2. 32x32 - medium
3. 48x48 - large

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is based on the XML markup and IRibbonExtensibility interface which add-ins should implement to get the custom UI displayed in Office applications. I'd suggest reading the following series of articles that describe the UI in depth:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Controlsize paramter in properties can be set to large.  I know it can be done in XAML but not sure how or in Outlook.Ribbon.Designer.cs...  Form my purposes it seems to work fine.